# Why is my resizing code failing?

Tags: flash, actionscript

The situation is, this resize code has always worked for me because I was using local images. I am now using a third party admin which feeds images through an `application/octet-stream`.

Whereas previously, I was loading the image with the `Loader::load` method but I am currently using the `Loader::loadBytes` to load the binary data because I am being fed a stream instead of an `image/jpeg`.

By switching to the stream, the code now fails to get past this line:

```
resizedImageData.copyPixels(e.currentTarget.getChildAt(0).bitmapData, cropRect, new Point(0, 0));
```

In this snippet:

```
    if((postcardWidth != postcardImage.width || postcardHeight != postcardImage.height) ) {
        ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , "IF");

        var resizedImageData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(postcardWidth, postcardHeight);
                    ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , "IF2");

        var cropRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(e.currentTarget.width / 2 - postcardWidth / 2, e.currentTarget.height / 2 - postcardHeight / 2, postcardWidth, postcardHeight);

                    ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , "IF3");

        resizedImageData.copyPixels(e.currentTarget.getChildAt(0).bitmapData, cropRect, new Point(0, 0));

                    ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , "IF4");


        var resizedImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(resizedImageData);

                    ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , "IF5");

        postcardFront.addChild(resizedImage);

                    ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , "IF6");

    } else {
        ExternalInterface.call( "console.log" , "ELSE");
        postcardFront.addChild(postcardImage);
    }
```

The postcardWidth is always 680, the postcardImage.width is 600, the postcardHeight is 442, and the postcardImage.height is 429.

It seems like the only culprit could be inconsistent `bitmapData`?

I have compared the working jpeg and the non-working jpeg using `diff` and opened them up both in `vim` and they start with the same character, end with the same character, and look 100% identical and span the same # of lines ( binary data ).

Does anyone have a clue why that line would work on one image and not the other?

**MORE CODE**

The `loadBytes` method is here: http://pastie.org/private/h463eu7cbx1vnhtxzq8xyg . This snippet is in an external `.as` file.

This code is from the fla, and is more of the code from the original snippet I pasted way up above in the question: http://pastie.org/private/vmwp4sw8urupdx91qny4w

Comment: whats the actual error you're getting? null reference? bad copy?

Comment: I don't get any compiler errors, it just silently fails to proceed to the console.log of `IF4`.

Comment: have you tried just adding the image that you're loading to the screen to see if it's fine? or copying to a BitmapData object that's the same size (i.e. no resizing)? Your stream isn't getting served compressed, is it?

Comment: also copyPixels() will throw an error if one of the required parameters are null. if you're not using the debug flash player, you won't see this

Comment: @divillysausages - I'm not sure how to load it to the screen or copy it to a BitmapData object - can you advise on how to debug this?

Comment: this line: `e.currentTarget.getChildAt(0).bitmapData` is what you're copying, so the `getChildAt(0)` should point to a `Bitmap`. Just add it to the stage, and see if it shows properly (btw, your code only seems to draw a cropped image, not a resized one). If that works, just do a straight copy (no resizing)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after taking the code you've pasted at pastie.org, I recreated the Image class on my end and ran some tests. Three things seem to be the problem. The first one is the line:

```
e.currentTarget.getChildAt(0).bitmapData
```

It's the `Image` class that sends out the `Event.COMPLETE`, meaning that it's the `currentTarget`. The first child, from what I gather from that class, is the `Loader` object that you add. `Loader` doesn't have a `bitmapData` object, so this one will throw a "can't access property from null object error".

The second thing is that, assuming that you're meant to be targeting the `Image` object here and the `bitmapData` is the `BitmapData` object that you create in the function `makeBitmapData()` (from http://pastie.org/private/h463eu7cbx1vnhtxzq8xyg), there's no public access to the `BitmapData`. In my version of the class, I added a getter.

Third is that the `Event.COMPLETE` event is dispatched *before* the call to `makeBitmapData()`, meaning that even if you could access it, it'd be null.

As you're using `ExternalInterface` to log your messages, I'm assuming this is running in the browser and you don't have the debug Flash player running, so you won't see the errors for `bitmapData` being null, and thus one of the parameters in the `copyPixels` call being null (which would throw an exception halting the progress of the swf).

The `Image` class I used if you want to test this (it works on my end):

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLStream;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class Image extends Sprite 
    {

        private var m_loader:Loader     = null;
        private var m_bmd:BitmapData    = null;
        private var m_bytes:ByteArray   = null;
        private var m_stream:URLStream  = null;

        public function get bitmapData():BitmapData { return this.m_bmd; }

        public function Image() 
        {
            trace( "Creating a new image" );
        }

        public function loadBytes( s:String = null ):void 
        {
            trace( "Loading image '" + s + "'" );
            // FOR EASY TESTING ONLY:
            if ( s == null ) 
                s = "http://onflex.org/flexapps/applications/ProgressiveImageLoading/jpg.jpg";        

            // create URLStream with listeners
            this.m_stream = new URLStream();
            this.m_stream.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, this._onStreamProgress );

            // create Loader for later
            this.m_loader = new Loader();
            this.addChild( this.m_loader );

            // create new ByteArray instance
            this.m_bytes = new ByteArray();

            // start the show!
            this.m_stream.load( new URLRequest( s ) );
        }

        private function _onStreamProgress( e:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            trace( "PROGRESS: " +  e.bytesLoaded + " of " + e.bytesTotal + " loaded!" );

            if ( this.m_stream.connected ) 
                this.m_stream.readBytes( this.m_bytes, this.m_bytes.length );

            if ( this.m_bytes.length == e.bytesTotal ) 
            {
                trace( "Image loaded!" );

                // get rid of the event listeners to avoid re-firing 
                this.m_stream.removeEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, this._onStreamProgress ); 

                this._onStreamComplete();   
            }
        }

        private function _onStreamComplete():void
        {
            this.m_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.INIT, this._makeBitmapData );
            this.m_loader.loadBytes( this.m_bytes );

            trace( "Stream complete, loading bytes" );
        }

        private function _makeBitmapData( e:Event ):void
        {
            trace( "Making bitmap data" );

            this.m_loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener( Event.INIT, _makeBitmapData );

            // set the bitmapData for the other public methods
            this.m_bmd = new BitmapData( this.m_loader.width, this.m_loader.height );
            this.m_bmd.draw( this );

            this.dispatchEvent( new Event( Event.COMPLETE ) );
        }

    }

}
```

And the Main class:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var m_image:Image = null;

        public function Main() 
        {
            this.m_image = new Image();
            this.m_image.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, this._onImageComplete );
            this.m_image.loadBytes();
        }

        private function _onImageComplete( e:Event ):void
        {
            this.addChild( this.m_image );

            var w:Number = 150.0;
            var h:Number = 150.0;

            var resized:BitmapData = new BitmapData( w, h );
            var cropRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle( this.m_image.width / 2 - w / 2, this.m_image.height / 2 - h / 2, w, h );

            resized.copyPixels( this.m_image.bitmapData, cropRect, new Point );

            var resizedImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap( resized );
            resizedImage.x = 450.0;
            this.addChild( resizedImage );
        }

    }

}
```

Does that fix it?